# How to change font-size for text within an <a> tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a website and inserting social media links in the footer. I am using Font Awesome's social media icons (see code to understand). To use the icons you must set the  tag with a class of whichever icon you would like. I am trying to have the icon bigger than the text associated with it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a style="font-size:25px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/username/" class="fa fa-facebook"> @username</a>

<a style="font-size:25px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/username/" class="fa fa-instagram"> @username</a>
```

This code results in the icon and the text associated being both 25px. I would like to change the font-size for the text only to 20px.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally messed up on the post. Should be fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the font awesome wrong. They always use the < i > tag for that so you won't have to separate it with css so this is how the html should look:

```css
a {
  font-size:20px;
}

a i {
   font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/username/">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> @username
</a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/username/">
   <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> @username
</a>
```

Also you don't have to apply the inline-block style to the icon, that is already done in the plugin CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Use the span tag

```
<a>@<span style="font-size: 20px">username</span></a>.
```

In this way the font size for username is targeted by the span.

Comment: This also changes the the font size of the anchor...

Answer (score 1):

Target the pseudo-element

```css
a.fa::before {
  font-size:25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/username/" class="fa fa-facebook"> @username</a>

<a href="https://www.instagram.com/username/" class="fa fa-instagram"> @username</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The icon appears in the generated content in `::before`. Target that pseudo-element with a stylesheet.

```css
.fa::before {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/username/" class="fa fa-facebook"> @username</a>

<a href="https://www.instagram.com/username/" class="fa fa-instagram"> @username</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your HTML version:

**HTML 5** states that the  element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)".

**HTML 4.01** specifies that  elements may only contain inline elements. `fas`  is a block element, so it may not appear inside an `<a>`.

You could use a `<div>` with `display: inline` inside of your  tag, if you use HTML5

Or a span, or some inline property if your HMLT  should be compatible < 5

```css
a{
font-size: 200px;
}

.fas{
font-size: 20px;
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="fas">hi</div>Hello</a>
```